# how to get the address of the main_arena?

Tags: c++, linux, heap-memory

i need to get the address of the main_arena to get some information of the struct malloc_state. Can anyone help me? I am writing a c++ code in linux environment (ubuntu).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there isn't main\_arena in libc.so symbol table, while there is one in malloc.c of glibc2.23?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960788/why-there-isnt-main-arena-in-libc-so-symbol-table-while-there-is-one-in-malloc)

Comment: Compile glibc with `MALLOC_DEBUG = 2` and  use `malloc_info()`. `of the struct malloc_state` there is `mallinfo()`.

Comment: In addition to using the default allocator, you may also consider use google's tcmalloc, it has built APIs to get the allocator's internal data without any black magic.

Comment: The libc's `main_arena` Changes with version changes, if you need to hack it, your code won't be portable, then it will be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is x86_64 architecture, you might get hints from:
[How to get the address of main_arena](https://progzakki.sanachan.com/en/how-to-get-address-of-main_arena/)

`main_arena` is defined in malloc.c (glibc) as the local symbol, so not exported. However, it can be found out by parsing symbol table with `dl_iterate_phdr` and `elf.h` if gdb running on your environment knows the address of `main_arena`.

Steps are:

1. call `dl_iterate_phdr` to get all information of shared library mapping on caller process.
2. catch libc.so.6 information when callback to be called, then you can get base address
3. parse elf information of libc.so.6, and find `.note.gnu.build-id` section
4. build file path according to `build_id`, this might be point the path of debug symbol.
5. parse elf information of debug symbol file, and find the offset address of `main_arena` from symbol table (.symtab section)
6. calculate actual address by `base address` plus `offset address`

gdb does the same way to load all symbols.